# Which Trans Music Manager equivalents exist for OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, audio, mp3

I have a Denon [DP-200USB](http://usa.denon.com/US/Product/Pages/Product-Detail.aspx?Catid=0033e08f-3edd-435b-946f-82784b5bc621&SubId=0&ProductId=3d665575-0ea6-479e-87e9-16cf7aaa74e5) turntable that converts analogue records (LPs) into MP3s (one MP3 per side) and stores them onto a USB memory stick.

This lovely piece of kit comes with some software called [Trans Music Manager (PDF)](http://denon.co.uk/DocumentMaster/UK/DP-200USB.pdf) that will automatically split tracks (based on silence between tracks) followed by naming and tagging them using [Gracenote](http://www.gracenote.com/).

Sadly this software runs under Microsoft Windows, for which I don't have a licence.

Are there any solutions out there that can do this easily under Snow Leopard? Free and open-source software is preferred, but paid-for alternatives would be considered.

Comment: You could install windows under virtual box.

Comment: @romeovs: Windows, even under VirtualBox, requires a licence (which I stated I do not have) and system updates each and every time I start the virtual machine. I am looking for an application, not an operating system.

Comment: Oops, I read over that. I just proposed this because it's the easy way out...

Answer (score 3):

I haven't personally tried it, but **[AudioSlicer](http://audioslicer.sourceforge.net/)** may be a good candidate

> AudioSlicer is a Cocoa GUI application
>   for Mac OS X that finds all silences
>   in an audio file and allows you to
>   split it into several smaller audio
>   files and to name/tag them properly.

Doesn't seem to do the Gracenote tag fetching, but you could use **[Jaikoz](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/jsp/overview/startup.jsp)** (tag from MusicBrainz db) or **[SimpleTagger](http://code.google.com/p/simpletagger/)** (tag from Amazon db) for that.

Answer (score -2):

Open in QuickTime Player and save as iPhone.

Comment: Please note that saving for iPhone will not split the track based on silence, nor tag automatically using Gracenote.